# Not counting DOM elements in React site with Cypress?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress

I can't count the number of DOM elements on a site written in React.

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />

context('Checking all components', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.visit('https://news-israel.com');
    });

    it('Checking posts', () => {
        cy.get('.posts-wrapper').find('a').should('exist');
        cy.get('.posts-wrapper').find('a').its('length').should('be.gte', 100);
    });
});
```

In this case, it doesn't find the "a" tags because React rendering them asynchronously and dynamically.
The "post-wrapper" class finds, followed by an exception:

> The following error originated from your application code, not from Cypress.
> Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined
> When Cypress detects uncaught errors originating from your application it will automatically fail the current test.

How to correctly count the number of elements in this case, so that you can "wait for the elements"?

The site I'm testing is in production - https://news-israel.com

Comment: The class you are looking for is `posts-wrapper` not `post-wrapper`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is coming from the app itself, and ultimately should be fixed in the app source.

But see this note in the log

> This behavior is configurable, and you can choose to turn this off by listening to the uncaught:exception event.

This links to an event handler you can use to debug. Add this to the top of the test to suppress the test failing when the error occurs.

```js
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
  // returning false here prevents Cypress from
  // failing the test
  return false
})
```

Now the test works, provide you use the correct class `posts-wrapper` not `post-wrapper`.

---

If you are able to fix the source, the error comes from the `react-typed` library, which is used in `BreakingNews.js` at line 75

```
<Typed
  strings={posts}
  typeSpeed={15}
  backSpeed={10}
  backDelay={5000}
  loop
/>
```

the posts variable is initially undefined, so you need a fallback value, e.g `strings={posts || []}`

Answer (score 1):

To globally Handle [Uncaught exceptions](https://docs.cypress.io/api/events/catalog-of-events.html#Uncaught-Exceptions), Go to `cypress/support/index.js` and write:

```
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
  return false
})
```

Now to count the number of elements you do it via [each()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each.html) or by using [Cypress.$](https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/$.html#Syntax)

Using `each()`:

```
cy.get('div.post-title').each((ele, list) => {}).then((list) => {
  cy.log(list.length)
})
```

Using `Cypress.$`

```
cy.get('div').find('.post-title').then(ele => {
  cy.log(Cypress.$(ele).length)
})
```

OR, As suggested by @Hiram

```
cy.get('div.post-title').then(ele => {
  cy.log(Cypress.$(ele).length)
})
```

Comment: Hey Alapan, you should do also do `cy.get('div.post-title')` in the second example, since posts are async.

Comment: True, but I tried using `cy.get('div').find('.post-title')` and find in that case it works as well. So I kept it there and also added your suggestion as well. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I found similar thing with my test - I think it has something to do with caching as it failed first then succeeded on retry.